# Background image not same on mobile

Tags: css, image, web, background-image, image-resizing

This is what the [background image looks like on the laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz2RI.jpg)

This is what the background image looks like on mobile [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3SCz.jpg)

As you can see the background is not correctly aligned, I want to see the exact same background on both.

Below is the cs code that I used and it doesn't help in resizing the image so that I see the same background image:

body {
    background-image: url('https://www.hdwallpapersbook.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Justice-League-Batman-Wonder-Woman-Aquaman.jpg');

```
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;

}

Comment: First, stop hotlinking images. The site owner can yank your access anytime and you're left with ugly looking site. Then read up about CSS responsive web design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

To force the image to contain itself in the container (this will most likely look a bit odd)

- background-size: contain;

or mess around with background position properties - so the part of the image you're seeing shifts in the container

- background-position-x: right;
- background-position:center

or look into object fit css properties:

- object-fit: scale-down
- object-fit: fill

or crop the original image and create a new image for mobile only view.